# Set/Get SystemTime in Java /C#

Tags: java, c#

I have this code in java which is about SystemTime:

```
  private static  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");

 //Gets the time of the boardtime object in milliseconds 
  public long getMs() {
          return super.getTimeInMillis();
  }
 //Sets the time of the boardtime object in milliseconds
  public void setMs(long ms) {
      super.setTimeInMillis(ms);
  }
```

I tried to convert it to C#:
For the first part, I used DateTimeFormatInfo class:

```
private static DateTimeFormatInfo sdf = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
```

for getting the system time in milliseconds I used TimeSpan:

```
 long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```

I do not know if what I have done until now is correct or not but I can not find any C# equivalent for the setTime.

This is what I have done until now:

```
  private static DateTimeFormatInfo sdf = new DateTimeFormatInfo();

   public long getMs(){
     long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
       return milliseconds;
   }

   public void setMs(long ms){  

   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to set the *system* time? Good luck, this is way harder than it sounds (or should be) in my experience. Please tell me you are just trying set an objects DateTime property.

Comment: :) please do not give me negative energy

Comment: yes, I am just trying to set an object DateTime!

Comment: Yes your `System Time` and supplying `DateTime` to a form are two different paths

Comment: So, I must change the title maybe...I am just supplying DateTime

Comment: Perhaps this might shed some light for you not sure if its what you are talking about,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172517(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I just need a C# equivalent for setTimeInMillis(ms)

Comment: Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and do an event on the `Tick`.  Then update your `Control` on the `Tick` event for the `DateTime` to whatever Format you need.

Comment: Normally you would just set a DateTime variable on the object in question, does that make sense? I'm not sure what setTimeInMillis does, but it sounds like a custom call if its for an object.

Comment: Sounds like `setTimeInMillis` is just a `format`.  So use `TimeSpan` and format it to `ms`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Exactly..it is used for a custom call

Comment: Ok, I guess what I am getting at is there isn't a question here yet. What are you trying to accomplish? If setTimeInMillis is a custom function, there is no "direct" translation for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set/get the time from milliseconds, you can do this with a C# [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private TimeSpan time

public void setMs(long ms)
{
    this.time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
}

public long getMs()
{
    return this.time.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getMs() as defined above returns the number of MS since 1/1/0001 ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172517%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) MSDN page, to set system time from C# you need to construct a SYSTEMTIME struct, initialize it properly, and pass it to the function SetSystemTime(). The page has a simple example that shows how to do that. How do we construct the right SYSTEMTIME struct? One can use the function [FileTimeToSystemTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes the number of ticks since 1/1/1601 (note the different year) and converts it to a SYSTEMTIME.

So, in short:

1. In your setMs() function, convert the parameter that was passed (ticks since 1/1/0001) to ticks since 1/1/1601 (basically, subtract 1600 years in ticks)
2. Construct a FILETIME struct from that value
3. Call FileTimeToSystemTime() to get the corresponding SYSTEMTIME
4. Call SetSystemTime() and pass that value

If there's an easier way, I'd be interested to know. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the time as milliseconds, then use the [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), constructed from a `DateTime` object using [TimeSpan.FromTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks.aspx). Create a [DateTime object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and manipulate the timestamp using milliseconds, then use the predefined [DateTime.AddMilliseconds method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by adding resp. subtracting milliseconds:

```
var now = DateTime.Now; // or new DateTime(2014, 05, 29, 21, 27, 05); 
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"));
var future = now.AddMilliseconds(1234567);
var past = now.AddMilliseconds(-1234567);
Console.WriteLine(future.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"));
Console.WriteLine(past.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"));
// get milliseconds from current date time object using TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds
var ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(now.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalMilliseconds);
```

The output is:

```
2014-05-29 21.27.05
2014-05-29 21.47.40
2014-05-29 21.06.31
63536995625703,1
```

Have a look at this MSDN article about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more custom date and time formatting options for a `DateTime` object.